# Creating a pop-up without a scroll bar or tool bar

Tags: html, popup, window

How can I replicate the plain window that appears on the Chrome Web Store where you click Add to Chrome when downloading an app?

The window/pop-up has no tool bar, no scroll bar and only has a button to close it in the far right corner, no button to minimise.

Comment: This is not a pop-up created with `window.open`. It is a container, positioned with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the popup in the Chrome Web Store is not a HTML or JavaScript generated one but a window component of the Chrome browser itself.

However, you can use CSS and JavaScript to build something like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function popup() {
        var disp = document.getElementById('floatingDiv').style.display;
        if(disp == 'block') disp = 'none';
        else disp = 'block';
        document.getElementById('floatingDiv').style.display = disp;
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #floatingDiv {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
       }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="javascript:popup()">Hello World!</a>
    <div id="floatingDiv" style="background: #dddddd; width: 320px; height: 240px;">
      I am a floating div!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you have full control over the display of the floating div.